# Log4j2 system property written as a file

Tags: java, log4j2

I use the following log4j2 configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5.5level %-60.60logger - %msg%n" />
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMatch="ACCEPT"
                    onMismatch="DENY" />
            </Filters>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
            fileName="${sys:log.file}"
            filePattern="${sys:log.parent.path}\$${date:yyyy-MM}\${sys:log.file.name}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>
                    %d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%30.30t]%-10.10level%-60.60logger - %msg%n
                </Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="60 MB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The system parameters are set when the file location is passed as a command line parameter and then the function reconfigureLog() sets the properties

```
public static void reconfigureLog(String logPath)
    {
        File logFile = new File(logPath);
        System.setProperty("log.file", logPath);
        System.setProperty("log.parent.path", logFile.getParent());
        System.setProperty("log.file.name", FilenameUtils.getBaseName(logFile.getName()));

        org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger rootLogger = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger) LogManager
                .getRootLogger();
        LoggerContext context = rootLogger.getContext();
        context.reconfigure();
    }
```

This is the sample usage of the scenario where I read the parameters from the command line and then set it later.

```
if (cmd.hasOption("logFile"))
        {
            String logPath = cmd.getOptionValue("logFile");
            Utility.reconfigureLog(logPath);
            logger = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);
        }
```

Every class has a static logger initialization like this:

```
private final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Connector.class);
```

The issue is when I run the application, `${sys.log.file}` is being created and then the corresponding log file from the parameters is created. Prodding through the parameters it seems that the parameter fileName under the RolllingFile is automatically added.

The debug log for log4j2 is:

```
2015-12-03 11:07:19,204 main DEBUG Calling createAppender on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile with params(fileName="${sys:log.file}", filePattern="${sys:log.parent.path}\${date:yyyy-MM}\${sys:log.file.name}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz", append="null", name="RollingFile", bufferedIO="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", Policies(CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=false), SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=62914560)])), null, PatternLayout(%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%30.30t]%-10.10level%-60.60logger - %msg%n), null, ignoreExceptions="null", advertise="null", advertiseURI="null", Configuration(<path>\Connector\target\classes\log4j2.xml))
2015-12-03 11:07:19,207 main DEBUG Starting RollingFileManager ${sys:log.file}
```

It can be seen that the system parameter is literally picked instead of substitution. I need to avoid the early initialization and start this loading only after calling the reconfigureLog method.
How can I avoid `${sys.log.file}` being created when I can use system parameters as part of my application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### TL;DR

Simply replace the ${sys:value} lookup with the ${main:--value} lookup.

### Explanation

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#AppMainArgsLookup

Combine this feature with configuration properties

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution

And you can do some very powerful configuration with the arguments without ever touching code.

Pay close attention to this from the PropertySubstitution docs.

> If no value is found for the key in the Lookup associated with the
> prefix then the value associated with the key in the properties
> declaration in the configuration file will be used. If no value is
> found the variable declaration will be returned as the value. Default
> values may be declared in the configuration by doing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Properties>
    <Property name="--file">log_file_path</property>
  </Properties>
  ...
</Configuration>
```

This means a configuration lookup like this `${main:--file}` would return the command line argument --file if it existed but if it did not would return the default value in the Properties declaration (im not sure if the name of the property would need to be "file" or "--file" for it to match correctly). There should be no need for code if your goal is to simply set the log file via argument upon startup.

Comment: Boy, that's a powerful way of substition. Thanks.

Comment: @dmachop : I know its 7 year old stuff. But do u remember if this solution worked just by changing ${sys:value} lookup with the ${main:--value} or you had to do some other change as well? For me still substitution is not happening.